# Using Least Squares method to determine unknown variables

Tags: standard-deviation, least-squares

Hey guys my next test is coming up and my professor gave us a study guide that we "should" be able to compete. Here is one of the questions I don't know how to attack:
[image]

I dont just want an answer. I really need to understand the process in solving a problem like this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=y/\sin(2\pi x)$ and compute the values of $z$.

Then draw $z$ as a function of $x$ on logarithmic scales, i.e. $\log(z)$ as a function of $\log(x)$.

What do you think of a linear regression then ?

Comment: Hello JJacquelin. I completed this but am not sure how it helps. Please explain

Comment: Did you compute the numerical values of $z=y/\sin(2\pi x)$ ? Did you draw the graph of $\log(z)$ as a function of $\log(x)$ ? Show it, in order to see if there is no mistake.

Comment: Hi JJacquelin.SOrry for the delayed response, I had to switch focus to another test but now that its done i really need to understand this one. Here is what it looks like:

Comment: OK. One can see on the drawing that the points are almost on a straigth line. So you can make a linear regression : $Z=A+b*X$ with $X=ln(x)$ and $z=Y=ln(y)$ with $A=ln(a)$

Comment: Ok I see how I can use this method to find the unknown variable but is this using the method of least squares?

Comment: What unknown variable are you thinking on ? There is no unknown variable. Only the coefficients A and b are unknown and they can be computed thanks to least squares method.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now I was confused in what exactly the Least Squares method was. I guess what I did in excel along with the linear regression is the least squares method. Thank You!

Comment: I don't see a linear regression in your excel page because the line is not a straight line and the values of the coefficients are not displayed. You have to study your course book. In order to check your futur results, see my own results below. Don't worry if the numerical values are not exactly identical : some small déviations could occur due to numerical rounding.

Comment: OK I finally understood the first part and found the same a and b values. I am just wondering how I would find the standard deviation for a and b because they are only one value each?

Comment: I am not sure if my professor meant standard deviation of x and y? That seems more manageable.

Comment: Obviously the formula $Y=a*x^b$ gives the computed values $Y_k$ which are not excatly equal to the given values $y_k$. That is where the deviations are, not elsewhere.

Comment: I agree that Y is where the deviation is but then when the questions asks for deviations in a and b, its a mistake correct?

Comment: This is probably a matter of vocabulary. Instead of "standard deviation" of $a$ and $b$, I would say "standard error". If so, you can find the définitions of SE(a) and SE(b) on this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html

Comment: It should be noted: in order to use least squares, you need to make the equation linear in the fitting variables, as discussed above. But, now you are minimizing the squared error in the new form - relative to log( y/ sin( 2 pi x) ) - and not in the original form relative to y. If a concern, this can probably be mitigated by weighting the data points according to y (reciprocal of derivative of log(y) wrt y).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the graph. I made it in excel. I also included the data I used in case I made a mistake. I am still not sure on how to find a and b from this. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is only the example of result. You have to do the computation to reach at this point.

Note that the drawing is with base e logarithm. If you prefer base 10 logarithm, it is equivalent : the result will be the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start with a sequence of $m=6$ data points $\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k} \right\}$ and the trial function
$$
 y(x) = ax^{b} \sin \left( 2\pi x \right).
$$
The least squares solution is defined as
$$ 
 (a, b)_{LS} = \left\{
(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \colon
\left(
y_{k} - a x_{k}^{b} \sin \left( 2 \pi x_{k} \right)
\right)^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$
The solution for this problem is 
$$
 \left[ \begin{array}{c}
  a \\
  b
 \end{array} \right]_{LS}
=
 \left[ \begin{array}{r}
  0.9946971138083956 \\
  -0.8158549983071405
 \end{array} \right]_{LS}
$$
which has the minimum 
$$
 r^{2}(a_{LS},b_{LS}) = 0.00661281
$$
This solution shown below with a white dot in the plot showing the total error as a function of the solution parameters $a$ and $b$.

The solution of @JJacquelin, the yellow dot, produces a higher total error of $r^{2} = 0.00708358$.

[image: total error]